# Method to find location of a given string in a sorted string array interspersed with empty strings

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm

The premise of this problem is a sorted array of strings that's interspersed (in no particular order) with empty strings, like so:

["at", "", "", "", "ball", ""]

My algorithm came down to finding the midpoint, and arbitrarily running my pointer left (or right) until it landed on a non-empty string so that I can then execute a binary search.

The solutions recommended checking both left and right elements until we land on a non-empty string. Once we have a non-empty string, we can proceed with binary search.

The solutions way on average will land much quicker on a non-empty string, but it requires more calculations to get there. Consequently, I'm struggling to compare/contrast the time costs of each approach.

Which is the more optimal approach?

Comment: Are you allowed to use .NET library calls or you have to implement if from scratch?

Comment: From scratch. As if I'm sitting in a coding interview for example

Comment: Can you remove empty string? ["at", "ball"]
To find the position in the first array of the found non-empty string, you can create another array of int: [0, 4] of positions in the first array ["at", "", "", "", "ball", ""]

Comment: To remove empty strings, I would have to scan through the entire array. This is O(N), and if I wanted to do O(N) then I can just scan through array to find my string. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: It is faster to test if a string is empty than to compare to another. And if the array is sorted, the binary search is in O(log(N))

Comment: Check in both directions at the same time, form the point where a binary search step lands you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the question is: when you land on an empty string, what algorithm visits less elements?

Suppose you have an sequence of `N` empty strings. With the suggested approach, if you land on the `N/2`th, you will visit `N` elements before finding a non empty string.

if you consider landing in the following positions, for each positions you end up visiting two less elements (one on the left and one on the right). So, your number of visited elements as a function of the landing position is:
`{2, ... N-4, N-2, N, N-2, N-4, ...}`.

If you visit only the element in a direction, your number of elements as a function of the position is {N, N-1, N-2...1}
Assuming that the probability of landing at any position in a range of empty string is the same, knowing that the sum of the first K number is

```
           K*(K+1)
sum(1,K) = ------
              2
```

and the average of the first K numbers is

```
             K*(K+1)
 avg(1,K) =  ------  =  K/2 + 1
              2*K
```

The average in the first case is `2 * ((N/2)/2 + 1)` =  `N/2 + 2`
The average in the second case is is `N/2 + 1`

So, it seems to me in terms of complexity the two approaches are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Even with empty strings, it is possible to perform a similar search as a binary search. When you visit an empty string, you should continue the binary search in one of the sides arbitrarily, then save that information in the stack, i.e. store whether this was a random direction or a wise direction. If at a certain point, the algorithm understands that was a wrong random direction, then tests the other direction with binary search and updates the stack of choice. If it was the right direction then just updates that stack and continues as normal binary search. This may lead to a linear time algorithm, however, depending on the distribution of the empty spaces, it may have an average of O (log n).

Answer (score 1):

On a glimpse I would say that the strength of binary search is to always cut the array to search in half by querying the center element. With gaps, that is no longer possible as the center element can be a gap. So what we would want to do is find the **closest non-gap element** to the center. In order to do so we'd look alternatingly left and right.

```
position  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
value     A   B   _   U   _   _   _   T   Z
```

Say we are looking for value B. We hit position 5 ( = (1+9)/10 ) which is a gap. If the algorithm were to always go right, then we'd walk on till position 8 and have the range to search restricted to 1-8 thus.

If on the other hand we had looked right, then left (etc.) then we'd have found position 4, which is much closer to the center and the range to search would be more restricted (1-4 in this example). Of course we can always make up an example where the always-look-right algorithm works better (e.g. when looking for T in above example :-), but generally it will be best to try to get as close to the center as possible, which is what the alternatingly-right-left solution does.

It was also suggested in a comment to remove gaps and you answered you'd have to read the whole array for this. This is true, but if you want to search the same range multiple times, that may be the fastest approach still, because you'd build that gapless arrray just once.

We'd build a new array containing the values and the original position and this array can be searched with pure binary search. Search this array several times and at one time it will pay to have built this new array.

```
position    1   2   3   4   5
orig. pos.  1   2   4   8   9
value       A   B   U   T   Z
```